# Is the general solution $y=Ae^{(\alpha+i\beta)x}+Be^{(\alpha-i\beta)x}$ valid for the complex and EQUAL roots of the auxiliary equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In the second-order differential equation, if the auxiliary equation has real and unequal roots ‘a’and ‘b’, then the general solution $y=C_1e^{ax}+C_2e^{bx}$ is different from the general solution of $y=(Ax+B)e^{ax}$ of real and equal roots ‘a’ and ‘a’.

I know the general solution of complex and unequal roots ($y=Ae^{(\alpha+i\beta)x}+Be^{(\alpha-i\beta)x}$), but I don't know whether the general solution of complex and equal takes the same form as that of complex and unequal roots.

Are they the same or different?

Comment: Whether or not $a,b$ are complex is unimportant. All of the same reasoning for $a,b$ being real applies. You still have to build one solution from the other using the Wronskian.

Comment: To get multiplicity in properly complex roots, an ODE with real coefficients would need to have order 4 or higher. The case $β=0$ leads to a double real root $α$.

Comment: a pair of complex roots are always conjugates of each other. If they are "equal"....it would just coincide with your case of "real and equal" roots. This should explain it for you!